# How to keep track of data structures for class instances in Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am using VSCode to write Python code.
I have a lot of different structures for data that is sent and received from other functions and stored in variables.
I tend to resort to put an example of the structure of the variable as a comment in the code, to help with quickly providing information when writing additonal code or refactoring.
This helps, but its also easy to forget to update the comments when the structure change.

To help with this I started using the `@dataclass` decorator to define classes of the different structures. This helps as I could then keep example of the structure of the data as a docstring in the class.

For example

```py
@dataclass
class NameAge:
    """
    [
        {
            "name": "Peter",
            "age": "22",
        }
    ]
    
    """
    name: str
    age: str
```

I can then create an instance of the class by doing

```py
name_age_obj = NameAge(name="Peter", age="22")
```

When I do mouse-over the "NameAge" part of the line above in VSCode I get a nice help text from the docstring that looks like this

[image: Docstring]

But to get to the actual question and problem, after I have created a variable called `name_age_obj` which is an instance of the class `NameAge` it is not possible to do mouse-over on `name_age_obj` to see the docstring and class help. It only shows as this:

[image]

Is it possible to get the mouse-over popup to show the class help? This would make it much easier and quicker to understand how different variables are structured.

Comment: Why do you have a fixing showing a dictionary within a list for a class which has nothing to do with a dictionary within a list? Why do you store age as an integer? Why do you actually need the list of all member variables in the doctring of an object? It feels like this is actually an [x-y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Maybe you should post your code for review in the codereview stack exchange site.

Comment: It is only a variable. You can imagine that if you import other packages, when you declare the variable, the prompt for this variable will appear a class prompt, which will appear very cumbersome and meaningless.